# Save reordered cells using CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

[image]I've looked everywhere for an answer, but I cannot find one...

After reordering my tableView cells, I would like to save these changes using CoreData. How do I do that, as simply as possible?

Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Set new order
        let itemMove = taskArray[sourceIndexPath.row] //Get the item that we just moved
        taskArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row) // Remove the item from the array
        taskArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row) //Re-insert back into array

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Add a specific sort order attribute to your entity and update it each time a re-order has been done.

Comment: In viewWillAppear, I update the taskArray with the Tasks. Is there a simple way of just saving the changes? 

do {
            try taskArray = context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
            tableView.reloadData()
            taskCountLbl.text = "\(taskArray.count)"

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

Comment: Yes please, i'd really appreciate this. Sorry I sound silly, but i'm completely lost.

Comment: i've added them to this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reindex the records after moving the rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Set new order
        let itemMove = taskArray[sourceIndexPath.row] //Get the item that we just moved
        taskArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row) // Remove the item from the array
        taskArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row) //Re-insert back into array

        tableView.reloadData()
        for (index, element) in taskArray.enumerated() {
            element.index = Int16(index)
        }
        do { try context.save() }
        catch { print(error) }
    }
```

And to fetch the proper order add a sort descriptor to your fetch request

```
let request = Task.fetchRequest()
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)]
```